# Sencha Ext Js Correct Username and Password

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have to program a Form which contains two Text Field Named: Login and Password and a button which is called "Login".

Now i have the problem that when i put my Data in there he always says its false.

```
var username = this.getId('user');
var password = this.getId('pass');

  if(username === "Peter" && password === "Bachmeier"){
Ext.Msg.alert("That is right");

}else{
  Ext.Msg.alert("Wrong");
```

I think my getter is wrong but i can't find the right one.

Thanks

Comment: if "user" and "pass" are both config properties you created and you are running this from the view's controller, then you would say this.getView().getUser() and this.getView().getPass().     In the sencha documentation, I recommend looking under "App Architecture" and "Core Concepts"  The class structure section will tell you about the getters and setters that are automatically created.  and understanding the ViewModel and ViewControllers will really help.  YOu can read through them in an hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

Assing name properties to both user and pass textfields.
Then
var values= this.getView().getForm().getValues();
values.user, values.pass